# Creation date of files in NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, xcode4, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to do the following:
create an array with filenames and creation dates from files online
compare this array with an array of filenames and creation dates from files in the NSDocumentDirectory.

How can I read the creation date from files in the NSDocumentDirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` method from [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can get the file modification date with `NSFileModificationDate` from the dictionary received by above method.